# Hybrid Mobile App Development Images

Tags: javascript, mobile, responsive-design, hybrid-mobile-app, onsen-ui

Just want to ask, if how do you handle images for multiple dpi screen. Are you creating multiple image to support different screen resolution. By the way Im about to use Onsen UI Framework.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean images to use inside your application? or images like app icon, splash screens etc.?

Comment: @JcDenton86 - yes, for example in an ecommerce mobile app like amazon, how will I handle the product images since there are multiple resolution of the smartphone.

Comment: Ok, if your images are coming through a custom API (i.e one you create) in JSON format, then you could send your images (urls) in many sizes such as thumb (150x150) to display to a list, medium (300x200), large (600x400) etc. That way you would parse your JSON and retrieve your images and display them accordingly in your views. If you want, I could give you an example of such JSON and how to parse it.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I understand now, one thing how do you resize your image for different densities of the device?

Comment: You can use a resource like this http://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/ . Otherwise you can use any image tool (i.e paint, gimp etc.) which can help you resize and create images in different sizes and resolutions.